# Comment Replies adding only to a particular comment

Tags: python, django

I am writing a webapp and would like to add comment/reply functionality. The comments work well, but while trying to add replies, all replies are saved to the first comment alone even when added from other comments.

I would like to make replies be linked to other comments.

Replies are linked to a particular comment using a ForeignKey() relationship and a related_manager.
I have tried a for loop to get each comment from the Comment() models in the template, and while it renders each comment well, I can't seem to link them to their specific replies.

```py
# models.py

class Comment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    email = models.EmailField()
    text = models.TextField()
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Comment %s by %s" %(str(self.text)[:20], self.name)



class ReplyComment(models.Model):
    comment_reply = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="replies")
    name_reply = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    text_reply = models.TextField()
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Reply by %s to %s" %(self.name_reply, str(self.comment_reply))
```

```py
# views.py
def article(request, slug):
   article = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
   comments = Comment.objects.filter(article=article)

    # comment form
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
      reply_form = ReplyCommentForm(request.POST or None)

      if form.is_valid():
         text = form.cleaned_data['text']
         email = form.cleaned_data['email']
         name = form.cleaned_data['name']

            # create the comment
         comment = Comment(article=article, text=text,
                              email=email, name=name)
         comment.save()

      if reply_form.is_valid():
         name_reply = reply_form.cleaned_data['name_reply']
         text_reply = reply_form.cleaned_data['text_reply']
         comment = Comment.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('comment_id'))
         reply_comment = ReplyComment(name_reply=name_reply, text_reply=text_reply, comment_reply=comment)
         reply_comment.save()



   else:
      form = CommentForm()
      reply_form = ReplyCommentForm()

   context = {'article': article, 'form': form, 'reply_form' : reply_form, 'comments': comments}

   return render(request, 'main/article.html', context)
```

```html
<!-- Comment Section -->
<section class="section scrollspy">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="collection">
            {% for comment in comments %}
            <li class="collection-item">
                <span class="secondary-content">{{ comment.time_stamp }}</span>
                <h5 class="title">{{ comment.name }}</h5>
                <p>{{ comment.text }}</p>

                <a href="#reply-modal" class="modal-trigger" data-target="reply-modal"><i
                        class="material-icons">reply</i></a>
                <div class="modal" id="reply-modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="{{ comment.id }}">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="row">
                                <p>Add a Reply</p>

                                <div class="input-field col s6">
                                    {{ reply_form.name_reply }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    {{ reply_form.text_reply }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="black white-text btn-small waves-effect">Reply</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="container">
                    {% for reply in comment.replies.all %}

                    {{ reply.name_reply }}<br>
                    {{ reply.text_reply }}<br><br>

                    {% endfor %}
                </div>

            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

I expect each reply added to be linked to their specific comments and linked as such.

I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: Looks good to me. Have you verified using Django admin or raw SQL that the foreign keys are actually set incorrectly?

Comment: I have, using django admin. I can add a reply to specific comments from there. I want to be able to add them from my templates.

Comment: I would suggest you to open your browser's inspector and watch what is POSTed when you click one of those reply-comment submit buttons.

Comment: can you add the code of your CommentForm and ReplyCommentForm ?

Comment: I have fixed the error on inspecting the modal element @Selcuk. The problem was that the id on the modal element was stuck to a single comment, and as such every comment rendered the same modal id. I fixed it by adding {{ comment.id }} to the id to make it dynamic. Thanks so much for responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the id on the modal element was stuck to a single comment, and as such every comment rendered the same modal id. I fixed it by adding {{ comment.id }} to the id to make it dynamic. Thanks so much for responding.

```html
<a href="#reply-modal{{ comment.id }}" class="modal-trigger" data-target="reply-modal{{ comment.id }}"><i class="material-icons">reply</i></a>
       <div class="modal" id="reply-modal{{ comment.id }}">
            <div class="modal-content">
```